# ErrorException in 939c885abda79cfdae4288b828415df7 line 38: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, view, models

I keep getting this error:

```
ErrorException in 939c885abda79cfdae4288b828415df7 line 38: 
Trying to get property of non-object
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
$episodes = Episode::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

$channels = Channel::lists('channel_name', 'id')->all();

return view('app.admin.episodes', compact('episodes', 'channels'));
```

And the view:

```
{!! Form::Label('Select Channel') !!}
<select>
@foreach($channels as $channel)
<option value="{{$channel->channel_name}}">{{$channel->id}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I am so clueless as to why this is so. My question is, is it not possible to pass data from more than one table to a view like i did in my code snippet in Laravel? I want to believe there MUST be a way to go about that in Laravel 5.1 but how???? Checked the documentations, seen many blog posts all leading me nowhere. Can anybody just save me this pain..... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To access the elements in the array, use array notation: `$channel['channelname']` and `$channel['id']` By  doing this: `$channel->channel_name`, you are trying to access an objects property.

Comment: That is not the correct way of accessing results from the `lists` method. There are no details for each collection item, neither objects nor subarrays.

Answer (score 1):

Starting Laravel 5.1, the `lists` method now returns a collection rather than an array. Calling `all()` convert it to an array. Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade

Seeing that you are using the Form Builder though, you can simply use the `select` method instead and let it handle it for you. Then, you can simplify your code to this:

```
{!! Form::label('Select Channel') !!}
{!! Form::select('channel', $channels) !!}
```

Change 'channel' to whatever input name you are using.

Comment: That is not the correct way of accessing results from the `lists` method. There are no details for each collection item, neither objects nor subarrays.

Comment: wow thanks @Thomas for this:
    The lists method now returns a collection rather than an array. Calling all() convert it to an array. That helped me a great deal and thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 1):

The `lists` method returns an associative array, in which the values come from the column passed as the first parameter (`channel_name`) and the item keys from the column passed as the second parameter (`id`). So in your case, you're getting an array that has the following structure for its items:

```
['id' => 'channel_name']
```

Which means that when iterating with `@foreach`, you need to use the key of the array as the id and the value as the channel name. Also you've switched out the value and text displayed, so the value should be the ID not the name, unless you want a dropdown that let's you select ID's:

```
<select>
    @foreach($channels as $id => $name)
        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

You can read more about how the `lists` method works, in the **"Retrieving a list of column values"** subsection form the [Queries: Retrieving Results](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results) Laravel Documentation.